# How can I avoid mountain driving between Thunder Bay, Ontario and Moab, Utah?

Tags: usa, driving, mountains

What is the best way to avoid driving right in the mountains? I am travelling via North and South Dakota, through to Casper, Flaming Gorge, and down to Goblin Valley, and am considering going through Salt Lake City.

Can I avoid mountain driving at all?

Comment: One reasonable way to evaluate this is to look at your route in Google Maps with the Terrain view.

Comment: Are you simply unfamiliar with mountain driving, or will you have a high-profile vehicle, or are you towing, or something else?

Comment: Other than flying, I can't see any way to cross the Rocky Mountains without driving through the mountains. Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: I suppose one could take Interstate 35 south to Oklahoma City, take Interstate 40 to Albuquerque, north on Interstate 25 a bit to Bernalillo, then US 550 up to the Four Corners, then proceed up to Moab. Nothing I'd call mountainous, but easier than, say, Iinterstate 70 west from Denver. Longer though.

Comment: A map would be very helpful here. Show your planned route and the mountains you don't currently like.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.